# MySQL query - how to look for certain string in the field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "story" as follows:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|   id   |    keywords                    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|    1   | romance,movie,drama            |
|    2   | newmovie,horor,comedy          |
|    3   | movie,scifi                    |
|    4   | newmovie,romance,drama,asia    |
|    5   | kids,movie                           |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I try a query to search 'movie' in keywords field as below:

```
SELECT id FROM story WHERE keywords LIKE '%movie%'
```

and the result is

> 1,2,3,4,5

but in this case I wanted the result is `1,3,5` (field value with `newmovie` not include). Can someone help me how the query to do it?

Thank you for your help..

Comment: `'movie%'` there. You really should normalize your db though.

Comment: ^ wait for it....................... V V V

Comment: if i use 'movie%' the result only return '3'

Comment: then use `FIND_IN_SET()` then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set or a regex https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: ...or the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) like this:

```
SELECT id FROM story WHERE find_in_set('movie', keywords) > 0;
```

Though you should really consider normalizing your table structure.

In this case, you could've stored one single keyword in one row, then the query would be simply like:

```
select id from story where keyword = 'movie';
```

and that would've been the end of it. No heavy string functions needed.

You could have structure like this:

```
keywords(id, name);

story(story_id,. . ., keyword_id);
```

then, you could simply join the two like this:

```
select s.* 
from story s
inner join keywords k on s.keyword_id = k.id
where k.name = 'movie';
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you.. @GurV

Comment: No. You definitely DON'T want to do this :-(

Comment: @Strawberry Can you explain why?

Comment: @Fredy - Because you should normalize your table instead.

Comment: @gurv I hate query but I like above query though, easy and simple. Can you explain what you mean by normalize and update ur answer.  So that others got informed.

Comment: @GurV Like this : story (id) , keywords (id, key), story_keywords (story.id,keywords.id). then i just make a query to joining all tables, like that? :)

Comment: @Fredy you could have keyword.id in the story table itself.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that "newmovie" can be found by "%movie%" you need only search "movie".

Comment: No result returning